# how to prevent usemin from overwriting original index.html file

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I'm using usemin and I generally like it, but I really dislike the fact that usemin overwrites my original index.html file. I have a pretty typical setup in my Gruntfile:

```
useminPrepare: {
  html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
  options: {
    root: '<%= yeoman.root %>',
    staging: '<%= yeoman.tmp %>',
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
    flow: {
      html: {
        steps: {
          js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
          css: ['cssmin']
        },
        post: {}
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Whenever I build using grunt everything in the end gets dumped into a dist directory. Most other tasks that need to do 'temporary' modifications copy and modify files in a .tmp directory.

usemin mucks with the actual index.html file though. I particularly don't like this because it makes Github think the file has changed every time I check in new code.

Is there a way to tell usemin to use the .tmp directory like most other grunt plugins?

I do specify my temp directory with:

```
staging: '<%= yeoman.tmp %>'
```

but that doesn't seem to prevent the index.html file from being overwritten.

Thanks.

**UPDATE** (per the comment below)

Here is the usemin task itself:

```
// Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
  }
},
```

and here is the grunt task that uses both useminPrepare and usemin:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
  'clean:dist',
  'wiredep',
  'useminPrepare',
  'concurrent:dist',
  'autoprefixer',
  'concat',
  'ngAnnotate',
  'copy:dist',
  'cdnify',
  'cssmin',
  'uglify',
  'filerev',
  'usemin',
  'htmlmin',
  'bridge:dist'
]);
```

Comment: Can you paste in here the grunt task that include useminPrepare?

Answer (score -2):

just do not perform filerev task. This is the task that modify the original html files.

Comment: Sorry, I clicked wrong. The file rev task takes files like foo.bar and turns them into foo.59bcc3ad.bar. This has no effect on the original file. The problem I face as far as I can tell is that the usemin task, when combined with bower, will try to 'inject' the bower components during a grunt build. Even though the file doesn't actually change in the end due to the way I have it setup. However, this messes up my version control on the file.

Comment: @lostdorje Oh, sorry for giving a wrong answer. You said 'inject' the bower components'references during the build process, and as I know, that is wiredep's functionality. So please checkout out its doc for proper usage.